# Failed to publish to Google Cloud Service with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-platform

I was flowing this guide [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart#install_cloud_tools_for_visual_studio), so i instaled all the things i was supposed to and created ASP.NET on Google Cloud Platform created project.

Then i created VM:
[VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkQnT.jpg)

And when i'm trying to publish i have that:

```
Publishing GcpProject1 to Compute Engine.
msbuild.exe "C:\Users\peter\source\repos\GcpProject1\GcpProject1\GcpProject1.csproj" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\fflssbvg.hc0"
Failed to publish project GcpProject1.
```

I turned off firewall and i have same versions of .net framework on server and locally.
Help me please to find the solution.

Comment: Forgot to mention: System - windows 10 x64. Using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Have you installed the Google Cloud SDK?  http://cloud.google.com/sdk

Answer (score 0):

I just face the same problem, the error message from asp.net is short and hard to figure out.

> **dotnet publish -o "C:\Users\Puzzle\AppData\Local\Temp\v1opor1f.mdb" -c Release
>
>    Failed to deploy project HelloWorld to App Engine Flex.**

I check other solutions , and find this works for me : https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/10/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-ASP.NET-Core-app-to-GCP.html

just use powershell to send command and that works. hope it helps